# How to bundle ES6 based React components and keep the bundle in ES6, using webpack?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

How can I use webpack to bundle Reactjs components that use ES6? The resulting bundle should be in ES6, it should not be transpiled to ES5.

There are a lot of good Reactjs/webpack examples available but all that I've found transpile to ES5.

Answer (score 2):

Just run [`babel-loader`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) without the ES2015 preset and add the [`transform-react-jsx`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/) plugin:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        plugins: ['transform-react-jsx']
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but got an error since I'm trying to use ES6 imports:
  Line 1: Unexpected token
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
  | import React from 'react';
  | import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  | import Component from './Component';

I guess this will work when using CommonJS import/export (which btw is in my view an acceptable solution for now) ?

Comment: @HelgiBorg Webpack 1.x does not support `import` syntax. Correct, you will need to use `require`, or add the [`transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/) transform

Comment: I found this example: https://github.com/krasimir/react-webpack-starter. It uses ES6, including ES6 imports, but transpiles down to ES5. By hacking the babel preset, I managed to get it to spit out ES6 bundled code. The trick was to strip down the babel-preset-es2015/index.js file down to having only: require("babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"). Next move would be to find or create such a preset. -- This is ofcourse just a small test, there will be issues. The first one is that UglifyJS doesn't support ES6.

Comment: @HelgiBorg You should add that as an answer to your question & mark it as the answer to help future readers

Answer (score 1):

I found this very nice example on how to configure Webpack with React and more: https://github.com/krasimir/react-webpack-starter. It uses ES6, including ES6 imports, but transpiles down to ES5.

By hacking the babel preset, I managed to get it to spit out ES6 bundled code. I changed the file node_modules/babel-preset-es2015 to:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs")
  ]
};
```

This is of course not an acceptable solution, what one needs to do is to find or create Bable preset that contains this.

The first thing I notice after this, was that UglifyJS doesn't support ES6. I suspect that there will be other issues down the road, so newbies like my self should perhaps stick to transpiling to ES5 a little bit longer.